Study the convergence/divergence of this series with only upper/lower bounds
I am stuck on this series, trying to show if it does converge or diverge. I cannot use any mechanical convergence criterion, only upper-lower bounding.
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^k\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{k} + (-1)^k}{k}\right)$$
I called $A_k$ the sequence inside the series. I tried to do something with $|A_k|$ but this doesn't lead me anywhere, indeed
$$|A_k| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{k} $$
Which doesn't tell me anything for the two sequences above diverge. Or better: it tells me that the series doesn't converge absolutely, but it may in other ways.
In the same way I wrote
$$A_k \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{k} \geq \frac{1}{k}$$
Now this apparently would ensure the divergence, but I am not enough brave to say I'm right. Indeed I believe I'm wrong.
Can you please guide me a bit more?

Note that the series is the sum of a convergent series and a divergent series. By the way, do not write $x\le y\ge z$ ... ever!!! If you need to do it just by the comparison test, then sandwich the series between multiples of the harmonic series.

Are you allowed to use the series alternating test?

@TedShifrin You're right. So I can just say it's divergent without any effort... (Thank also for the advice, it's actually a bad writing indeed)

@SineoftheTime No :/ only $\leq$ or $\geq$ techniques, with known series like geometric series, harmonic series, $1/n^2$ series or exponential

Do you know that $\sum (-1)^k/\sqrt k$ converges?

Well, I'm certainly using the Leibniz test (alternating series test) to say one of the terms gives a convergent series ... So just go for bounding it below by a multiple of the harmonic series. Why don't you write up an answer below?

@TedShifrin If I write something like $$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{k} \leq A_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{k}$$ I keep getting nothing...
But maybe I can do this?
$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{k} \leq A_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{k}$$

Oh yeah. I was being silly.

@SineoftheTime I am not sure to get the point... I mean I have a series which is a sum of a convergent series and a divergent series. I hence know nothing, for for example even the series of $1/k - 1/k$ is a difference between two divergent series, hence unknown, but it's actually $0$ so it converges. How can I use the fact that that part converges?

If $\sum a_k<\infty$ and $\sum b_k=\infty$, then $\sum( a_k-b_k)=\infty$. It can't converge, since also $\sum b_k=-\sum(a_k-b_k)+\sum a_k$ would converge

@SineoftheTime How do you prove with boundings that the series of $(-1)^k/\sqrt{k}$ converges? I only obtained that it's not absolutely convergent...

that's why I asked if you know $\sum (-1)^k/\sqrt{k}<\infty$ or if you can use Leibniz test

@SineoftheTime Ah, sorry I didn't understand correctly then... Then I don't know (I mean I could know, because you told me, but I don't know how to prove it in this way)

Your original series is equivalent to $\sum_k (\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}+\frac 1k)$, you certainly know that the harmonic series diverges. If $\sum_k\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}$ converges, then the original series diverges. To prove the convergence of $\sum_k\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}$, use Leibniz test (i.e. show that $k\mapsto k^{-1/2}$) decreases monotonically to $0$. Is it clear now?

@SineoftheTime It would be, if I would be allowed to use Leibniz test :D Sigh.

Note that \begin{align*}
\sum\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k} &= -1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big(\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{2n+1}}\big) = -1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}}\\ &=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n})\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}}.
\end{align*}
Now finish with an obvious comparison with $\sum n^{-3/2}$.
